# pointer to a structure in a nested structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have a 6 levels of nested structures. I am having problem with last three levels. The program compiles fine but when I run it crashes with Segmentation fault. There is some problem in assignment is what I feel. Kindly point out the error.

```
typedef struct {
    char addr[6];
    int32_t rs;
    uint16_t ch;
    uint8_t ap;
} C;

typedef struct {
      C *ap_info;
} B;

typedef struct {
    union {
        B wi;
    } u;
} A;

function1(char addr , int32_t rs, uint16_t ch, uint8_t ap) {
    A la;
    la.u.wi.ap_info->addr[6] = addr;
    la.u.wi.ap_info->rs = rs;
    la.u.wi.ap_info->ch = ch;
    la.u.wi.ap_info->ap = ap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not allocated memory for the struct pointed to by `la.u.wi.ap_info`, or set the `la.u.wi.ap_info` pointer itself.  You need something like:

```
la.u.wi.ap_info = calloc(1,sizeof(C)); // allocate a C instance and 
                                       //  point la.u.wi.ap_info at it
```

...with a later `free(la.u.wi.ap_info);` when you no longer need the struct.  Or you could point it at a pre-existing struct provided you ensure that the struct you point it to will exist until you're done with it.

Additionally, the line:

```
la.u.wi.ap_info->addr[6] = addr;
```

is incorrect; it assigns the character in `addr` to the seventh element of the array, which only has space for six elements (so it's out of bounds).  If `addr` was meant to be a string you're copying into the structure, then its type should be `char *` not `char`, and you need something like:

```
strncpy(la.u.wi.ap_info->addr, addr, 5); // copy up to 5 chars
la.u.wi.ap_info->addr[5] = '\0'; // explicitly null the sixth char
```

instead of simple assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating memory for the pointers

Comment: @dpka6 I would accept Dmitri's answer - it is much better than mine

Comment: Sure Adrian. You too pointed out my mistake correctly. Thank you both.